# Not able run chrome - 4794 abort (core dumped) google-chrome-stable

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to open Google chrome on my Ubuntu 14.04 . But I get the following error.

```
command :   # google-chrome-stable
Result :      abort (core dumped)  google-chrome-stable

command :   # google-chrome
Result :      abort (core dumped)  google-chrome
```

I tried re-installing but this didn't help.

Comment: I tried the quoted answer .. Same issue . I cannot open chrome

Comment: This is probably the right duplicate: [Google Chrome not starting (“Aborted (core dumped)”)](/q/803068)